# Repairing corrupt shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, extensions, corrupt

I have a corrupt Shapefile. But, All other files are still good. How can I create or generate a Shapefile from only the ".shx .prj .mnd .drw .dbf"?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If the `.shp` is lost, you have no geometry to repair.

Answer (score 2):

Esri provides a general step by step guide to "repair a corrupt shapefile" [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/how-to-salvage-a-corrupt-shapefile.htm)

> Use the Check Geometry tool. Problems with the data are reported while the tool is executing or in the output table. View the output table after execution.
>
> An empty table indicates that the tool found no bad geometry.
>
> If bad geometry is reported, use the Repair Geometry tool.
>
> Try using the Repair Geometry tool.
>
> Attempt to copy the data to a geodatabase. Afterward, also try copying it back to a new shapefile.
>
> Try selecting all or a subset of the features and export the selected features to a new shapefile or feature class.
>
> If the data is on a network drive, copy it to a local drive. If the data is on a local drive, try copying it to the root of the primary drive, for example, C:.
>
> Check for illegal field names in the attribute table.
>
> Field names can only have 10 characters. Field names must start with a letter.
>
> Field names must not contain any spaces or special characters, except for the underscore character.
>
> File names must not contain any special characters, except for the underscore character. Generally speaking, spaces in shapefile names work in ArcGIS for 
>   Desktop; however, for testing purposes, rename the shapefile so it has no spaces.
>
> Remove all index (spatial, attribute, and geocoding) and metadata files in Windows Explorer. That is, remove all files except .shp, .dbf, and .shx. Verify that a copy of each of these files has been made before removing them.
>
> Try opening the shapefile on another computer.
>
> Try opening the shapefile in another software application—preferably ArcView GIS 3.x.
>
> Try bringing the data into another feature class either by using the simple data loader or by copying and pasting in an edit session.
>
> If the data is still not repaired, and the first two suggestions above reported the feature IDs of the bad records, try manually removing them in an editing session.
>
> Try bringing the .dbf part of the shapefile into Microsoft Excel and resaving it as a dBASE 4 file. Do not make any other changes to the file.
>
> Try making a field calculation in ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcView GIS 3.x using the field calculator. The field calculator may stop on the corrupt record.

Answer (score 1):

The .dbf file contains the attribute table for the shapefile. **If the attribute table contains X/Y coordinates,** you can recreate a point shapefile from the .dbf file alone.

If not, you can use this method to import the table without any geometry.

Make a copy of the .dbf file, and open the copy in Excel. Check to see if any of the attributes contains coordinates.

> Save as... > Save as type: CSV (comma delimited)

Back in QGIS, Add delimited text layer
[image]

In the dropdown menus next to X field and Y field, choose the relevant columns. Remember that Y = latitude and X = longitude.